# using piped input of a file, not able to get the file name piped to it instead of the file content

Tags: c, file, input, pipe, stdin

I will be passing a text file using pipe.

```
cat ./file.txt | ./pargrep word
```

I tried to get the file name

```
fgets(buf, NULL, stdin);
```

How can I get just the file name instead of the file content, which I get when used gets. I need to read the file, which is pretty huge and need to read it twice.

Comment: If you look yourself at the output of `cat ./file.txt` how can you tell the filename? Your program gets the same info and will be able to use the same method which you use. If the file name is not visible there, then you can make it visible, by e.g first piping the file name and then the content.

Comment: @Yunnosch how do i pipe for file name in the program.

Comment: Maybe as simple as `echo ./file.txt | ./pargrep word`? To pipe name AND content  requires some commandline syntax magic or, probably easier, a short script.

Comment: I think you might not need the file name in the case of piped input. Could you double check that the class assignment really requires that? I ask because the specific job to find the filename (if you only get the commandline as shown in the question and you can only influence the implementation of pargrep) might actually be impossible. And I would optimistically assume that your teache did not set an impossible task...

Comment: assignment is to get the content directly from a file, file would be a large file and need to grep for a word in file and print it, just like grep but need to implement it through threads. im storing the whole file in a string array. Before storing it i got to check for the number of lines in it and then start storing it, so i go to read the file twice. stdin is not allowing me to read it twice .So, i was planning on getting the file name. any clue on how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the pipe.  I assume you are writing the program ./pargrep? I would pass the name of the file you want to process as the first argument to your pargrep program.  The second argument would then be "word"

Then you would open the file by name in the program.

Comment: his is for an class assignment, i have to process both input from a file and piped input. Is there a way to process piped input to get the file name

Comment: Roger is correct, there is no way for your pargrep app to determine the name of the file that is cat(ted) to the pipe. Since you need to read the file twice, you could consider writing the contents that you read from STDIN to a temporary file and then open it up again so you can read it a second time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `cat` outputs the contents of the file. If you want the filename, run as

```
echo ./file.txt | ./pargrep word
```

but better to use dernst suggestion rather than this

Comment: this is for an class assignment, i have to process both input from a file and piped input. Is there a way to process piped input to get the file name

Comment: @Roger not if you pipe the output of `cat`. Does the assignment perhaps want you to take the filename as a parameter (as dernst said), or take contents directly from stdin (which would include piping from `cat`)

Comment: assignment is to get the content directly from a file, file would be a large file and need to grep for a word in file and print it, just like grep but need to implement it through threads. im storing the whole file in a string array. Before storing it i got to check for the number of lines in it and then start storing it, so i go to read the file twice. stdin is not allowing me to read it twice. any clue on how it can be solved?

Comment: @Roger, save all the data into a buffer first, then you can go over it as many times as you want.

Comment: saving data in buffer and then to a pointer would cause an extra overhead, we are awarded marks based upon speed comparison between the actual grep and multi threaded grep. looks like that it the only way left. Thanks for ur time